# What does w.p. mean in formulas?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning

I'm checking Facebook's paper about Prophet algorithm. I don't understand a part of formula, "w.p.". It's hard to search on Google. Could anyone help me understand this?

[image: formula with w.p.]

https://peerj.com/preprints/3190/ (Page 11 has this formula.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means "with probability". So here, there is a $\tfrac{T-S}{T}$ probability that $\delta_j = 0$, and a $\tfrac{S}{T}$ probability that $\delta_j$ is drawn from a $\text{Laplace}(0,\lambda)$ distribution.